# Add ClaimsIdentity via OWIN AuthenticationManager.SignIn is not working

Tags: c#, owin, claims-based-identity, authorize-attribute, current-principal

I did create custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that should handle Jwt Bearer token and then create `ClaimsIdentity`. But when I send request again, anyway I can't see authorized user and must create `ClaimsIdentity` again and add user to `CurrentPricipal` again. What I'm doing wrong?

```
public class JwtAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private readonly string role;

        public JwtAuthorizeAttribute()
        {
        }

        public JwtAuthorizeAttribute(string role)
        {
            this.role = role;
        }

        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var jwtToken = new JwtToken();
            var ctx = actionContext.Request.GetOwinContext();
            if (ctx.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return true;
            if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Contains("Authorization"))
            {
                var token = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
                try
                {
                    IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
                    IDateTimeProvider provider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
                    IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, provider);
                    IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
                    IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder);
                    var json = decoder.Decode(token, SiteGlobal.Secret, verify: true);
                    jwtToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JwtToken>(json);
                    if (jwtToken.aud != SiteGlobal.Audience || jwtToken.iss != SiteGlobal.Issuer || role != jwtToken.role)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                catch (TokenExpiredException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                catch (SignatureVerificationException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, jwtToken.unique_name));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, jwtToken.role));
            ctx.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, identity);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            HttpContext.Current.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signin is used to create a cookie. Do you have a cookie Auth middleware to handle the signin?

Comment: No, I'm using jwt token, but seemes like completely confused with with how to create authorized user in this case.

Comment: JWTs are designed to be sent and validated on every request. Your call to signin is not doing anything, that only works with cookies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explainig a lot. Actually you may add it as answer.